# How to output in xslt under arbitrary path?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following problem in xslt. Given the sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>A</cd>
  <dvd id='A'>B</dvd>
  <dvd id='B'>C</dvd>
</catalog>
```

I want to output tags `cd` as `CD` and `dvd[@id="B"]` as `CD`, and all the other `dvd` as `DVD`. The simple transform with three templates (cd, dvd and dvd with id=B) works fine, but produces something like this:

```
<CD>A</CD>
<DVD>B</DVD>
<CD>C</CD>
```

The problem is that the validation schema expects `DVD`s to follow `CD`s, so CD->DVD->CD is wrong. I came up with this schema to tackle this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cd">
    <CD>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </CD>
    <xsl:if test="../dvd[@id='B']">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../dvd[@id='B']" mode="keep"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dvd">
    <DVD>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </DVD>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dvd[@id='B']" mode="keep">
    <CD>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </CD>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dvd[@id='B']">
    <!-- do nothing -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does the job but seems to be slightly wordy and complicated - I'm hackingly checking if a node exist, transforming it, and when it occurs in a normal flow of processing I'm ignoring it - and I'm not even sure if it's entirely correct.

Could you suggest a way in which `dvd[@id="B"]` would have only one template which would output `<CD>` under a path like "after the last cd on this level"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="catalog">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cd | dvd[@id='B']"/>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dvd[not(@id='B')]"/>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
    <CD>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </CD>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dvd">
    <DVD>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </DVD>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dvd[@id='B']">
    <CD>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </CD>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or, if you prefer:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="catalog">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cd | dvd[@id='B']"/>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dvd[not(@id='B')]"/>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd | dvd[@id='B']">
    <CD>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </CD>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dvd">
    <DVD>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </DVD>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that the result is not well-formed XML, as it has no single root element.

Comment: Doh... Thanks a lot :) This is that kind of xslt mindset that's difficult to figure out yourself, but once you're there it makes perfect sense and will help me solve many more problems in the future.

Comment: Btw in terms of not being well-formed, the examples were just a simplification of a much more complicated real-life problem.